# Curl returning null response when run from artisan command for cron job

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

Trying to run an API which will give me the updated temperature and humidity values but the curl function is not working as it gives a NULL reponse and throws error. running the from the terminal to test it

code:

```
        class updateTempHumHourly extends Command
    {
        /**
         * The name and signature of the console command.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $signature = 'update:temphum';

        /**
         * The console command description.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $description = 'Update temperature and humidity readings hourly';

        /**
         * Create a new command instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            $options = array(
                'cluster' => 'ap2',
                'useTLS' => true
            );

            $pusher = new \Pusher\Pusher(
                'osdifnerwion4iownfowinf',
                'dofhewofhewofnowenfid',
                '7asdkland',
                $options
            );

            $thinkers = t::where('user_id', '!=' , NULL)->where('thinker_status',1)->get();

            foreach($thinkers as $t)
            {

                $temp = [
                    'action'=>'list_slave',
                    'mac'=> $t->thinker_MAC,
                    'type' => 'all',
                    'appkey' => 'nope'
                ];

                json_encode($temp);

                $response = Curl::to('http://103.31.82.46/open/open.php')
                ->withContentType('application/json')
                ->withData($temp)
                ->asJson(true)
                ->withHeader('Postman-Token: d5988618-676e-430c-808e-7e2f6cec88fc')
                ->withHeader('cache-control: no-cache')
                ->post();

                foreach($response['slaves'] as $s)
                {
                    if(array_key_exists("temp",$s) && array_key_exists("hum",$s))
                    {
                        $slave = sd::where("connected_thinker_MAC",$response['mac'])->where("device_id",$s['slave_id'])->first();
                        $slave->temperature = $s['temp'];
                        $slave->humidity = $s['hum'];
                        $slave->save();

                        $array = [];
                        $array['temperature'] = $s['temp'];
                        $array['humidity'] = $s['hum'];
                        $array['id'] = $s['slave_id'];

                        $pusher->trigger($t->user_id."-channel","s-event",$array);

                        \App\helper\log::instance()->tempHumLog($s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the foreach loop throws an error that $response is equal to null. the curl function is not working from here but working fine regularly. help. i need to run this task every hour to get the average temperature and humidity.

Comment: So your code works on browser but not from command line?

Comment: Seems like the API is responding with an HTTP 500 error, at least on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that your code works somewhere that means that there is something wrong with your server and not the code itself probably (since it's a CURL issue).

Inside your php.ini file there is this line : `extension=php_curl.dll` to enable curl. Uncomment it on your server that you have the crons to make curl work. This should solve your problem.

Testing localy the api you provide us returns a 500 but if you say that it works for you i assume that this is just an example and the problem is in CURL itself.

Comment: The issue was not in the code. The eloquent mapping was returning garbage values for some unknown reason. But thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Yes that's what i mentioned as well that since the api returns 500 the issue is not in the code itself. Good to hear that your issue is solved !!!